# recvfrom() не принимает пакеты

Tags: python, сокет

В простой имплементации traceroute программа зависает на recvfrom().

```
import socket
import random

dst = "google.com"
hops = 30
ttl = 1
port = random.choice(range(33434, 33535))
dst_ip = socket.gethostbyname(dst)
while True:
    receiver = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_RAW, socket.IPPROTO_ICMP)
    receiver.bind(('', port))
    sender = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM, socket.IPPROTO_UDP)
    sender.setsockopt(socket.SOL_IP, socket.IP_TTL, ttl)
    sender.sendto(b'', (dst, port))
    addr = None
    try:
        data, addr = receiver.recvfrom(1024)
    except socket.error:
        pass
    finally:
        receiver.close()
        sender.close()
    ttl += 1
    if addr[0] == dst_ip or ttl > hops:
        break
```

Comment: а если не 1024 поставить, а 1, например?

Comment: @gil9red ничего не изменилось

Answer (score 0):

Вот рабочий пример traceroute
[создан для Python2](https://gist.github.com/shivanshu3/4b757e244b9d7ef74457b61cb8ba36c1) или [для версии Python 3.6](https://gist.github.com/zhongWJ/4783e74f04f7832d749f65fcd821d813)